# How To Convert ISOFormated date to Python datetime?

Tags: python, django

I have a datetime string in the format `2017-08-30T10:21:45.337312+00:00` send from django server using `timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).isoformat()`

I need to parse it back to a timezone object. How to do it?

I tried the following but its not working

```
kolkatta_tz = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")
kolkatta_tz.localize(datetime.strptime(product_list[index][5], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'))
```

It throws the following error:

```
time data '2017-08-30T10:21:45.334742+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

Comment: It's not working isn't a very useful problem description for people to help.. but I'll take a guess it's because you're missing the `%` before the Z...

Comment: i added the error description.

Comment: And did you try adding the percent sign before the Z and see if that works?

Comment: u mean '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%Z' ? yes I tried that too but same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dateutil's parser.parse method:

```
import dateutil

date_string = '2017-08-30T10:21:45.337312+00:00'
datetime_object = dateutil.parser.parse(date_string)
print(repr(datetime_object))
```

Gives you:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 30, 10, 21, 45, 337312, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

To get the `tzinfo` object:

```
datetime_object.tzinfo
```

Example:

```
print(datetime_object.tzinfo)
```

Outputs:

```
tzutc()
```

### Sample Function:

```
import dateutil
import datetime

def get_timezone(date_string):
    dto = dateutil.parser.parse(date_string)
    if not isinstance(dto, datetime.datetime):
        return None
    return dto.tzinfo
```

#### Function Tests:

```
for o in xrange(-12, 12, 2):
     dstring = "2017-08-29T01:58:47.12321"
     if o >= 0:
         dstring += "+{:02n}:00".format(o)
     else:
         dstring += "{:03n}:00".format(o)
     print(get_timezone(dstring))
```

#### Returns:

```
tzoffset(None, -43200)
tzoffset(None, -36000)
tzoffset(None, -28800)
tzoffset(None, -21600)
tzoffset(None, -14400)
tzoffset(None, -7200)
tzutc()
tzoffset(None, 7200)
tzoffset(None, 14400)
tzoffset(None, 21600)
tzoffset(None, 28800)
tzoffset(None, 36000)
```

Answer (score 2):

The python-dateutil package can parse ISO 8601 and other date and time strings and.

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686Z') # RFC 3339 format
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 20, 56, 35, 450686, tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2008-09-03T20:56:35.450686') # ISO 8601 extended format
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 20, 56, 35, 450686)
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('20080903T205635.450686') # ISO 8601 basic format
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 20, 56, 35, 450686)
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('20080903') # ISO 8601 basic format, date only
datetime.datetime(2008, 9, 3, 0, 0)
```